# software buttons height

Tags: android

How I can calculate height of software buttons (like in galaxy nexus or razr motorola hd) ?

Personally, I suppose that `DisplayMetrics.heightPixels` attribute is height of all screen without software buttons height and with height of status bar.

Hence, **software buttons height** = **specification height** - **DisplayMetrics.heightPixels**.

Exemple for nexus 7:

`75(soft button height) = 1280(spec height) - 1205(DisplayMetrics.heightPixels)`

Im right ? please confirm.

Comment: Can you please give a full code snippet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My assumption is right.

to generalize question and prove it, here manual measurement what I have done on telephone and tablet from screenshots :

## SOFTWARE BUTTONS HEIGHT

- **samsung galaxy nexus**

portrait: 48 dp
1280 - 1184 == 96 px == 48dp xhdpi

landscape: 42 dp
1280 - 1196 == 84 px == 42dp xhdpi

( attention!: in landscape, this is not height but width of software button placed on right side of screen)

- **on nexus 7**

portrait: 56dp
...

landscape: 48dp
...