# Finding aspect ratio of an android device

Tags: android

In my application the UI does not look good for the newly introduced android devices with aspect ratio 4:3. In order to provide a better UI for such tablets I need to detect the aspect ratio of the device at runtime and need to make necessary UI adjustments.
How do I detect if the android device has an aspect ratio of 4:3?

I tried this for a Nexus 9 device (which has an aspect ratio of 4:3).

Used the following code:

```
DisplayMetrics widthMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(widthMetrics);
int width = widthMetrics.widthPixels;

DisplayMetrics heightMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(heightMetrics);
int height = heightMetrics.heightPixels;

float aspectRatio = (float) width/height;
```

Nexus 9 has a resolution 1536 X 2048. In the above code I receive the width value as 2048. But the height value 1440 (instead of 1536). Due to this, the aspect ratio I receive is 1.4222223 and not the expected 4/3(1.3333).

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: tried `Display#getRealSize` / `Display#getRealMetrics` ?

Comment: getRealSize and getRealMetrics methods are supported from API level 17, but the minSdkVersion of my app is 15. Hence I can't be using these methods

Answer (score 0):

Nexus 9 uses software buttons (home, back, ...). This height of those buttons will be substracted from the displayHeight.
The height is 48p in portrait mode, 42dp in landscape mode. So you are missing 96 Pixel in height: 48dp * 2 (xhdpi screen Nexus 9)

More information:
[software buttons height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233336/software-buttons-height)